# How to wrap text of a javafx chart legend

Tags: javafx, charts, legend

Can anyone please help me with wrapping the text in a legend of a javafx chart. I have pie charts and bar charts. All the legends are placed at bottom.  I tried the following but couldn't get it working.

```
    for (Node node : pie.lookupAll(".chart-legend")) {
                if (node instanceof Text) {
                    System.out.println("Text instance");
                    ((Text) node).setWrappingWidth(380);
                    ((Text) node).setManaged(true);
                }
                if (node instanceof Label) {
                    System.out.println("Label instance");
                    ((Label) node).setWrapText(true);
                    ((Label) node).setManaged(true);
                    ((Label) node).setPrefWidth(380);
                }
  }
```

**EDIT:**
See the highlighted part. Still some text is not visible.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it. Trying to wrap text in css didn't work as label width cannot be controlled there. So the following code can be used to wrap the text programmatically.

```
for (Node node : pie.lookupAll(".chart-legend-item")) {
                if (node instanceof Label) {
                    System.out.println("Label instance");
                    ((Label) node).setWrapText(true);
                    ((Label) node).setManaged(true);
                    ((Label) node).setPrefWidth(380);
                }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at the CSS documentation?
This link is refering to the chart legend section:
[JavaFX CSS Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#legend)

As mentioned, it's of the type Label, so we can have a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#labeled) as well.
`-fx-wrap-text` possibly does the trick. Of course you would need to write and attach your own CSS file to your program...

For a more detailed example, please refer to your JDKs `jfxrt.jar`, unzip it and look for the `modena.css`, which is the default CSS file.

Regards.
Daniel

***Edit***: I got the following snipped to actually have an impact on or  application after all:

```
.chart-legend {
   -fx-background-color:  transparent;
   -fx-padding: 20px;
}

.chart-legend-item-symbol {
   -fx-background-radius: 0;
}

.chart-legend-item {
    -fx-text-fill: #191970;
}
```

But it is important, where you place it in your CSS. In my first attempt, I placed it **above** the CSS rule, which set the default label text color.
When I noticed this, I put it at the end of my CSS file: et vóila - it worked.

So please have a second look, that your placed accordingly in your own CSS.

Comment: I tried `-fx-wrap-text` in the css. `.pie-legend-symbol {-fx-wrap-text: true;}`. Its not working for me

Comment: As far as I understand the documentation `.pie-legend-symbol` should be just the graphics node (otherwise the naming would be kind of misleading). Have you tried `.chart-legend-item` for the legend label itself?

I guess you would need to update either your code above to the "item" or give it a try with a separate CSS file...

Comment: I only have one relative complex application to test it one, where other factors might interfere with my changes. When I add the legend regarding lines taken from this older JavaFX2 tutorial, it doesn't work for me as well: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/css-styles.htm - in this case I hae to admit, without further tests on my side, I'm a bit lost as well. Sorry, pal!

Comment: Please have another look at my answer: I updated it after another test.

Comment: I am able to see the difference in my chart legend's appearance but still I am not able to wrap the text of the legend item. I have edited the question to add an image depicting the problem

Comment: Have you added the line `-fx-wrap-text: true;` to the `.chart-legend-item` class? If so, then I guess, it has something to do woth the width properties of the actual Label. In this case you could try the programmatich approach. But this might require some hacking. I changed the colors for the lines in a LineChart (which are normaly restricted to 8 different or so) programmatically - I could update my answer tomorrow accordingly, if you want, since I have no access to the code right now. But first give the `-fx-wrap-text` in the CSS another chance...

Comment: I added `.chart-legend-item {
    -fx-text-fill: #191970;
    -fx-wrap-text: true;

}` in css only.. not in my code but it didn't wrap the text.. also here i couldnt get any parameter that could reduce the width of the legend label.

Comment: I got it.. thanks.. in the code I have mentioned I just had to change `.chart-legend` to `.chart-legend-item` and it worked.